# send all drafts in apple's Mail

Tags: email, scripting, applescript, containers

I'm new to scripting and am trying to write a simple script for mail. which I am going to use to send all emails in my draft folder at an ical event. however I am running into an error im not sure how to debug. here is my script

```
tell application "Mail"
set draftMessages to every message in drafts mailbox
repeat with theMessage in draftMessages
    set theSender to (sender of theMessage)
    set theSubject to (subject of theMessage)
    set theContent to (content of theMessage)
    set theRecipients to (to recipients of theMessage)
    set theAddress to (address of theRecipients)

    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, sender:theSender, address:theAddress, visible:true}

    end repeat
end tell
```

and here is the events log with sensitive info replaced as blah.

```
tell application "Mail"
get every message of drafts mailbox
    --> {message id 23241 of mailbox "Drafts" of account "BLAH", message id 23236 of mailbox "Drafts" of account "BLAH"}
get sender of message id 23241 of mailbox "Drafts" of account "BLAH"
    --> "Blah Blah <blah@blah.com>"
get subject of message id 23241 of mailbox "Drafts" of account "BLAH"
    --> "test 2"
get content of message id 23241 of mailbox "Drafts" of account "BLAH"
    --> "test 2"
get every to recipient of message id 23241 of mailbox "Drafts" of account "BLAH"
    --> {to recipient 1 of message id 23241 of mailbox "Drafts" of account "BLAH"}
Result:
error "Can’t get address of {to recipient 1 of message id 23241 of mailbox \"Drafts\" of
account \"BLAH\" of application \"Mail\"}." number -1728 from «class radd» of {«class 
trcp» 1 of «class mssg» id 23241 of «class mbxp» "Drafts" of «class mact» "BLAH"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to make a new message? The message already exists in your drafts folder and there is no reason to make a new one. This should be sufficient to do what you want:

```
tell application "Mail"
set draftMessages to every message in drafts mailbox
    repeat with theMessage in draftMessages
        send theMessage
    end repeat
end tell
```

If this isn't what you want, then you need to rewrite your question.

Comment: does not work by me, got an error.  `doesn’t understand the “send” message.`

Comment: @JulienColomb My solution is almost 8 years old. It may not work with the current versions of Apple Mail, AppleScript and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the new message outside of the tell block...

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set draftMessages to every message in drafts mailbox
    repeat with theMessage in draftMessages
        tell theMessage
            set theSender to (sender of theMessage)
            set theSubject to (subject of theMessage)
            set theContent to (content of theMessage)
        end tell
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, sender:theSender, visible:true}
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I thought that would work to but it just runs forever when I do that. :( thanks though